# Change an img height so it's at a certain aspect ratio to it's width with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image that I need to change the dimensions of with jQuery.  The image width should be the same as the width of it's parent div.  The parent div is a responsive column container, so it's width is dynamic(fluid).  Once the width of the image is changed, the height should also be changed to a value that would correspond with the aspect ratio of 16:9 in relation to the image's width.  So let's say the column width is 1920... the image height would then be 1080.  How can I modify my code to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#featured-articles').find('.featured').each(function(){
        var slide = $(this);
        $(this).find('img[rel="featured_preview"]').each(function(){
            var new_width = slide.width();
            var new_height = ?????
            $(this).prop("width", new_width).prop("height", new_height);
        });
    });

});

<div id="featured-articles">
     <div class="featured">
          <img src="slide.jpg" rel="featured_preview">
     </div>
     <div class="featured">
          <img src="slide2.jpg" rel="featured_preview">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested your code, but is this what you want?

```
var new_height = Math.round(new_width*9/16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 100%;` to your img css. This naturally keeps the aspect ratio of the original picture (this assumes your original image is at a ratio of 16:9 -- which is a pretty valid assumption because you shouldn't be stretching/distoring images)

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/ymas7tkx/)

Comment: Yeah these images will be uploaded by users and my form requires exact dimensions but on the rare chance that the image goes through without being validated this will fill the div.

Answer (score 0):

here a simple example :

html code :

```
    <div id="test" style="width:300px">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />    
   </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

javascript code (using jquery) :

```
        var aspectRatio = 9/16; 
        $('#test img').css('width','100%');
        var imgWidth = $('#test img').css('width');

        // we have to remove the suffix px in imgWidth otherwise we will get 
        // a NaN value when we attempt to use that value in arithmetic 
        // operations

        imgWidth = imgWidth.replace('px','');  

        // above the image width is converted from percentage format(%) to a 
        // static value for example 300px

        var newHeight = imgWidth*aspectRatio;


        $('#test img').css('height',newHeight+'px');
        console.log(imgWidth+'\n');
        console.log(newHeight);
```

you can try the example      [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9286j2L3/)